# R plotting word clouds in custom shape (e.g logos)

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-cloud

I've a question - is there a way to plot my wordcloud in a certain shape (in accordance to a picture?) e.g apple logo etc.?
Cheerio,
Nadine

Answer (score 1):

The base shape of `ggwordcloud` is a circle: the words are place by following a circle spiral. This base shape circle can be change to others (cardioid, diamond, square, triangle-forward, triangle-upright, pentagon or star) using the shape option. .

You can extend with a .png
Here is a example with a heart (heart.png):
See here: https://lepennec.github.io/ggwordcloud/

```
data("love_words")
set.seed(42)
ggplot(
  love_words,
  aes(
    label = word, size = speakers,
    color = speakers
  )
) +
  geom_text_wordcloud_area(aes(angle = 45 * sample(-2:2, nrow(love_words),
    replace = TRUE,
    prob = c(1, 1, 4, 1, 1)
  )),
  mask = png::readPNG(system.file("extdata/hearth.png",
    package = "ggwordcloud", mustWork = TRUE
  )),
  rm_outside = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 40) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "darkred", high = "red")
#> Some words could not fit on page. They have been removed.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.
png::readPNG is an own package, isn't it?
I think this is why it did not work? I used a png.file but it did not recognise my file.

Comment: Are there any other requirements for the png.file?